# Как построить график зависимости названия недели от числовых значений

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Вот [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L-QSMefLv-Zr5trloxzD2Z7pLKh72nhG/view?usp=sharing). Хочу построить график на котором на оси абсцисс будут названия дней недели (столбец `weekday`), а на ординате значения столбца `visits` соответственно.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно не помню уже кто такие абсциссы с ординатами, поэтому вот оба варианта размещения. Через `Seaborn` всё делается моментально. В принципе, и `Pandas` тоже всё умеет и сам рисовать, но там параметры не интуитивно понятные, я их не помню.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('weekday_day_visits.csv')
sns.barplot(x = 'visits', y = 'weekday', data = df);
```

[image: график]

Вариант с поменянными `x` и `y`:

```
sns.barplot(x = 'weekday', y = 'visits', data = df);
```

[image: график2]

Update:

Добавил вариант с гистограммой на основе вашего кода:

```
import itertools
df['day_weekday'] = [w + '_' + str(d) for (w, d) in itertools.zip_longest(df['weekday'], df['day'])]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.barplot(x = 'day_weekday', y = 'visits', data = df);
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'  
);
```

[image: график3]

Comment: я не знаю, какой свежести у вас jupyter notebook, но matplotlib inline уже давно не обязателен ;)

Comment: @strawdog Я всё делаю в Google Colab. Хм, и правда не обязателен, спасибо )

Comment: Это не совсем то чего я хотел. Мне хотелось проследить динамику посещения по дням недели, на протяжении всего месяца. Под тип того, что у меня в решении, хотя конечно гистограмма смотрелась бы лучше, но я уже не стал заморачиваться:)

Comment: @ВиталийТодоров Добавил ещё вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
day_weekday = pd.read_csv('weekday_day_visits.csv')

#создаём столбец day_weekday и заполняем его
day_weekday['day_weekday'] = day_weekday['weekday']
import itertools
day_weekday['day_weekday'] = [w + '_' + str(d) for (w, d) in \
        itertools.zip_longest(day_weekday['weekday'], day_weekday['day'])]

plt.close('all')
#figsize=(12,5) - размеры холста
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,5))
ax.plot(day_weekday['day_weekday'], day_weekday['visits'])

#повернуть подписи по оси x
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]